# How can i remove same image placed couple of times for my 100's of product

Tags: magento-1.9, import, image, duplicate

**How can i remove same image placed couple of times.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Magento does not have `any logic to remove same name of images`. You should remove those manually.

Or do custom code

**A note that** in magento if you **upload same name images more once then**  from *second times* ,magento *rename images* example `image_1.Extesion,image_2.Extesion` etc

Comment: what is the prblm is, when i upload 500's of product, only 100 images, uploaded, remaining not uploaded but loading goinon whole day

Comment: Do u understand what i am try to tell you

Comment: is sessions time out problem ??
or any limit for bulk image upload ??